# Shiny crashing when recalculating plot

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to make a reactive output graph in shiny, but everytime I try to move the slide the whole app crash, and in console I get a [... truncated] message. Here's the code for the UI:

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(
    width=8, offset=2,
    h1("Palabras reguladoras en secuencias no   codificantes",align="center",style="padding-top:15px;font-size:28px")
)),

 fluidRow(
 column(
    width=12,
    h3(strong("Represión de UTR´s en ratón con microRNA"),
      align="center",style="font-size:20px;line-height:10px")
    )
),

 wellPanel(align = "center", sliderInput("largo", label = h3("Número de     bases en la palabra"), min = 1, max = 10, value = 6)),

wellPanel(align = "center", plotOutput("grafica"), tableOutput      ("tabla"))

))
```

And the code for ther server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

 observe({

 rm(list=ls())

largo = input$largo

all_arr = colSums(oligonucleotideFrequency(allutrs, width = largo, step     = 1))
rep_arr = colSums(oligonucleotideFrequency(represedutrs, width = largo,     step = 1))

vector_n = sum(all_arr) - all_arr 

tabla = data.frame(rep_arr, all_arr, vector_n, sum(rep_arr))

 names(tabla) = c("x", "m", "n", "k")

tabla$hyper = phyper(q = tabla[,1], m = tabla[,2], n = tabla[,3], k =       tabla[,4], lower.tail = FALSE)

 tabla$hyper_log = -log10(vector)

 cuantil = quantile(tabla$hyper_log, probs = 0.99)

 tabla$arriba = tabla$hyper_log >= cuantil

centradi = c()
nombres = c()
ia = 0
i = 0
for (i in 1:length(tabla$hyper_log)){
    if (tabla[i, "arriba"] == T){
    ia = ia + 1
    centradi[ia] = tabla$hyper_log[i]
    nombres[ia] = row.names(tabla[i,])
    }
 }

 names(centradi) = nombres

 #valor_y_graf = tabla[names(centradi),6]
 #valor_x_graf = which(tabla$arriba == T)

#partes = list(
#function() plot(tabla$hyper_log, main = "Densidad", xlab =         "Palabras", ylab = "DistribuciÃ³n hipergemetrica (-log(10))"),
    #function() abline(cuantil,0, col = "red"),
    #function() text(valor_x_graf, valor_y_graf, names(centradi),   cex=0.6,pos=4, col="blue"))

#output$grafica = renderPlot(for (i in 1:3) partes[[i]]())
output$grafica = renderPlot(plot(tabla$hyper_log))
output$tabla = renderTable(head(tabla))
  })

})
```

I think it is because of the high memory use, especially in the for cycle, because when took it away it run. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: why do you have rm(list=ls()) in there? you dont need to clear the workspace! I suspect this causing the issue

Comment: I cleared the workspace because the memory used what high. I tried without the rm and it still crash. But, thanks!